# How can I select just the tag I click on and get the Attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four anchor tags that have an attribute that I need to be able to set to a var when they are clicked.

```
<a href="#" class="myatag" variant="1234" />
<a href="#" class="myatag" variant="1235" />
<a href="#" class="myatag" variant="1236" />
<a href="#" class="myatag" variant="1237" />
```

Right now I am doing the following

var myVar = $("a.myatag").attr("variant");

That sets the myVar to 1234 but that is the only variant I am able to get no matter which one I click.

I need it to set myVar to whichever a tag is clicked.

Comment: I will recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attributes, Which can be easily manipulated using jquery's `.data()` function. Heres [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gnt2J/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctRfq/)

As click internally calls "on" method use following for optimized call:

It means on clicking the class named "mytag" .do callback.Now get its custom attribute varient.

```
var myVarVariable;
$('.myatag').on("click",function(){
    myVarVariable=$(this).attr('variant');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo and the answer this works for me! I would up vote it if I could.

Comment: Now u can do so !  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myatag').click(function(){
    var myVar=$(this).attr('variant');
});
```

if you want the myVar to be global you must do this: `window.myVar=$(this).attr('variant');`

and then call it whenever needed like this: `window.myVar`

UPDATED:

```
$('.myatag').click(function(){
    window.myVar=$(this).attr('variant');
});
```

Comment: But myVar will vanish, being local to the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myVar;
$("a.myatag").click(function () {
    myVar = $(this).attr('variant');
});
```